# altair python package gives "Illegal instruction" on Raspberry PI

Tags: python, altair, raspberry-pi-zero

In my RaspberryPI ZERO W I got strange error when trying to import altair module in python script.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python3
Python 3.7.3 (default, Jul 25 2020, 13:03:44) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import altair
Illegal instruction

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ pip3 freeze
altair==4.2.0
```

Does anybody have an idea if there is a version, which works on RaspberryPi? Or any other idea why it is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Illegal Instruction` means that you are importing a C extension that is compiled incorrectly for the system you are using. Altair itself doesn't have any C extensions, but it depends on a number of libraries that do include C extensions, which you can see in its [`requirements.txt` file](https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/blob/master/requirements.txt):

```
entrypoints
jinja2
jsonschema>=3.0
numpy
pandas>=0.18
toolz
```

I would suggest trying to import each of these libraries to narrow-down which package is incorrectly installed, and then search for information on how to correctly install the problematic package on RaspberryPi ZERO.

Comment: Thank you! It helped. I narrowed down modules and found problematic one: `pyrsistent` had a [problem with newest release] (https://github.com/tobgu/pyrsistent/issues/231). Soluton was to update to version 0.17.3